# How to get SublimeText to indent html within ES6 ``

Tags: html, sublimetext3

I am placing html tags with es6 backticks. it looks something like this;

```
@Page({
  template: `
 <div>
  <p>
  <span>
  </span>
  </p>
 </div>
  `
})
```

Within the backticks, sublimeTExt does not indent the html. Is there a way to make this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime is not seeing your HTML code for what it is because the built-in JavaScript language definition [scopes](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#scopes) content inside backticks as `string.template.js`, but not `text.html.basic`, which is the base scope for HTML. As a workaround, you could use an external HTML formatter (I use [`HTML-JS-CSS Prettify`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify), there are many others) to properly indent the HTML. Alternatively, you could just write your HTML in a different view with HTML syntax, then copy and paste into your JS template string.